# obtener id de un article

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como obtengo una id cuando esta de la siguiente forma?

```
<article productid="555">
```

lo quiero es agregar una etiqueta con ese id especifico pero no se como llamarlo.

intente con el "#" pero pues no me funciono.

cuando le pongo el article si le agrega el elemento a todos los articles, pero como no todos llevan la etiqueta entonces no me sirve.

```
var $flagHighligthContainer = $('article').find('.highlight');
        var $productDiscount = $('<p>').addClass('flag flag-envio-gratis').html('Envio Gratis');
        $flagHighligthContainer.empty().append($productDiscount );
```

Comment: ¿esa etiqueta la generas tú? No es buena idea inventarse un atributo así, es recomendable ponerle el prefijo `data-`

Comment: no la genero yo, el cms la crea asi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos te dejare lo siguiente:

```js
//el id del producto
value = 555
//obtengo el valor o contenido de la etiqueta
var custom = $('article[productid="' + value +'"]').text();
alert(custom);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article productid="555">Smart Tv</article>
```

De esta forma obtienes los valores de una etiqueta con X id para **productid**.

Bien ahora para colocar un valor  a dicha etiqueta seria asi:

```js
idProduct = 555
//nuevo contenido
contenido = '<h2>MI CONTENIDO</h2>'
//ASIGNO EL NUEVO CONTENIDO
$('article[productid="' + idProduct +'"]').html(contenido);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article productid="555"></article>
```

Espero te sirva..!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes buscar un elemento que tenga un atributo con cierto valor con la sintaxis

```
elemento[atributo=valor]
```

En tu caso, puedes hacer algo como

```js
$('article[productid=555]').each((indice,elem) => console.log(elem))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article productid="555">
<article productid="556">
```

Comment: donde esta el 555 podría remplazarlo por una variable con varios id?